# PHP / SQL - Datetime format messed up PHP Side

Tags: php, datetime

I'm storing a datetime timestamp in the database (SQL Server).
I simply use this to get the current time: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`
which works fine.

In the database it looks exactly the same (the format), however, when I get the datetime from the database the format is completely off.

The date is for example displayed in the database as `19-4-2016 13:29:36`, but when I read the data in PHP it becomes `apr 19 2016 01:29:36:000`.

My code for reading it from the database:

```
$dateFromDB = /* Sql query here.. */;
$myTimestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($dateFromDB));
```

The `$dateFromDB` variable echos: `apr 19 2016 01:29:36:000`

The `$myTimestamp`echos: `1970-01-01 01:00:00`

The date is stored in the database as `datetime`, **be aware that the date format looks good inside the database table**, it's messed up when it is being read at the PHP side.

It looks like this in the database:
[image]

Comment: How do you fetch it from the database? It should be "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" [according to the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html): "*the format for these values is 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS[.fraction]'*". Are you certain it's stored as a `DATETIME` or is it actually a `VARCHAR`? Regardless, you can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. **Also, are you running MySQL or MsSQL?** You've tagged it with MySQL but "Microsoft SQL Server" is not MySQL.

Comment: if you are storing correctly then why you are using `strtotime` and `date` function. Simple `echo $dateFromDB`. I don't think you need to convert value

Comment: @h2ooooooo I added a picture in my OP.

Answer (score 2):

From Question :**The date is for example displayed in the database as `19-4-2016 13:29:36`**

`19-4-2016 13:29:36` should be `2016-04-19 13:29:36 (Y-m-d H:i:s)` format in Database.

Answer (score 0):

@Dubb :- I used the same date to store in the database and then tried to retrive it. I am able to retrive in the same format as I had stored earlier. I used this code to fetch from database :-

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
     $ff =  $row["dates"];
     echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($ff)) . "<br>";
   }
} 
else 
{
   echo "0 results";
}
```

If possible please describe your table column format

Comment: Hey, it's just 'datetime'. When I click the column i'm able to select from a calender, so SQL server reads it as a proper date aswell.

Comment: Have you set proper timezone in php?